# Chrome Extension - Content Script unable to find elements by class name

Tags: dom, google-chrome-extension, getelementsbyclassname, content-script

I am attempting to access elements with a specific class name from a page using a content script of a Chrome extension.  So far the content script can successfully find an element with a specific id using document.getElementById(), but using document.getElementsByClassName() or jQuery's $(".className") yields no results.  For the sake of testing, I used 'header' as my class name and every website I ran the extension on resulted in an array length of 0.  Any ideas what I might be missing?  Here's what I have been testing with:

```
manifest.json
=================
{
    "name": "Sample Extension",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Sample extension",
    "icons": {"128": "icon.png"},
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", "<all_urls>"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "browseraction.png",
        "default_title": "Sample",
        "popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
            "js": ["scripts/contentscript.js"],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}

contentscript.js
===================
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("header");
alert( elems.length );
```

Comment: Probably a silly question, but are you sure there are elements in the HTML with a style class of "header"?

Comment: Well, to be honest, I wasn't actually using 'header' as my class name, I just figured it would be more generic for the sake of this example.  The test website I was using is http://supercollider.dk/2010/04/chrome-extensions-for-web-hackers-part-%E2%85%A1-background-pages-255 and I was using 'says' as my class name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is very basic and straightforward, it *can't* be a cause of problem. In fact, I just used your exact code (with "says" class and website you provided) and `alert()` says every and each time `1` (which is correct).

My best guess is that you haven't reloaded your extension after making changes in `contentscript.js` OR some other extension is interfering and causing this strange behavior. Try disabling other extensions before testing your extension.

Comment: Thanks for testing this, @Konrad Dzwinel!  Interestingly, now when I reload the page, the script alerts me with the correct number, `1` , but when I use the browser action, it gives me a result of 0.  I'm definitely relieved to see that I can collect class elements at _some point_, I guess this opens up a whole new pandora's box of _what_ is accessible _when_.

Comment: Uno momento. You never said that you are using browser action to do the same thing as your content script is doing. You are mixing two things here.

Comment: Actually, I think I may know what's happening.  I think the content script is running at "document_end" as instructed by the manifest. Then my popup.html, which was triggered by the browser action, runs <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/contentscript.js"></script> at the end of its body, which it does, but in the context of the popup's DOM, not the page that the browser is currently viewing.  Thanks again, Konrad, for helping me reach this epiphany!

Comment: Exactly, I couldn't have said it better :) From a popup you can't access a webpage directly. You'll have to use a background page as a proxy probably (search for "message passing" and check out the video on the bottom of this page: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html). Good luck!